# Trying to connect IP security camera to Raspberry Pi 3 using only a Ethernet cord

Tags: camera

I have an IP camera outside of my Garage, I have little to no internet out there so I cant connect using wifi. so I am wondering if I can connect my Camera using a ethernet cord to the Raspberry PI itself. Kind of like a usb web camera in a way.

Thank you, Any suggestions will help me greatly

Comment: If your camera has an ethernet port, yes you can connect it to a RasPi 3B/3B+.

Comment: The answer to your immediate question is of course you can. What kind of functionality you may get out of it is another matter which will depend on the kind of camera you have and what software comes with it.

Answer (score 1):

If you are going to run an Ethernet cable to the camera outdoors, you can't just use a regular cable: the weather will hammer it.  Also, max length of a Cat6 Ethernet cable is 100 meters, so depending on how far your garage is from your switch, that could be a limiting factor.

Here's a Cat6 Ethernet 20 meter cable I run to an outside AP in my back garden so I can surf from my hammock: can buy if for under £12 from amazon.co.uk [here](https://www.amazon.co.uk/gp/product/B00EOTHCAO) The cable is designed to be buried.
[image: Cat6 Outdoor Ethernet cable]
You could even use this 24AWG Cat6 cable to power your Pi-Cam via a POE switch, which would also enable you to remotely reboot it or start it from a down state by merely disabling and re-enabling the port on the POE switch it's connected to.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can.
But you must be sure, that IP Camera and Raspberry Pi are on same network.
example:
Raspberry Pi's IP address: 192.168.0.1
IP Camera's IP address: 192.168.0.2